# Can WSO2 identity server generate username given the first and last name during self-registration?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible in WSO2 Identity Server self-registration process to request only the First and Last name of a User and generate a username instead of asking the user to enter the desired username?

Comment: You can tweak the JSP page of the `accountrecoveryendpoint` webapp to concat the Fname and Lname to generate the userName. You will have to make sure that the userName is unique. Also, the generated userName has to comply with the Regex defined in the user store level.

Comment: @NipunThathsara this seems like a good place to try the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The default WSO2 identity server [self-registration](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/self-registration/#self-registration) process does not allow generating username by the given first and last name.

But according to the wso2 documentation of [Customizing WSO2 Identity Server UIs](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizing-identity-server-uis/), you can customize the WSO2 Identity Server self-registration process to request the First and Last name to generate a username by concatenating the first and last name accordingly.

The generated username should be unique and obey the defined username regex in the user store. In the documentation of [Working with Properties of User Stores](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/working-with-properties-of-user-stores/#working-with-properties-of-user-stores), you can find the user store properties related to username regex. Therefore you should verify that the concatenation of first and last name, generates a unique username that complies with the username regex.

Comment: This seems doable, However, the verification method is where I'm stuck at. How can we verify the uniqueness of the username?